# Back arrow button not placed in center in toolbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have displayed a back button (up button) in the action bar but it is not getting displayed in the center of the bar.

As can be seen in this image

[image]

I have set a minimum height for the toolbar and I cannot change that.

My xml code is as follows :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/offence_title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    android:minHeight="150dip"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:maxLines="3"
                        android:textColor="#FFF"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fine_bold"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/offence_details"
                style="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/fine_bold"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:textIsSelectable="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove padding top from your `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

**Like:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/offence_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:minHeight="150dip"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"    //remove this line from your xml
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:paddingRight="15dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `android:layout_width` to your custom height and `android:minHeight` to `?attr/actionBarSize`. This ensures that fixed elements are displayed along the top (centered within the `minHeight`) while the entire height is still expanded to your larger height.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  android:id="@+id/offence_title"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="150dip"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:paddingBottom="15dp"
  android:paddingTop="15dp"
  android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
  android:paddingRight="15dp">
```